# "cannot find appsink" - Gstreamer with OpenCV4, Python under Linux environment

Tags: python-3.x, linux, opencv, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

Under an embedded Linux environment, and with Python, I am trying to get a video feed from my USB Camera,

Using OpenCV "default" implementation works perfectly :

```py
video = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_V4L2)
```

But because I need to customize the pipeline, I am trying to use directly the gstreamer pipeline, but I get warnings and the pipeline is not created.

I have tried various pipelines like :

```py
pipeline="v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw, format=YUY2 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw, format=BGR ! appsink"
video = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

or

```py
pipeline = (
            "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! "
            "video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,format=BGR ! "
            "videoconvert ! "
            "appsink drop=true sync=false"
        )
video = cv2.VideoCapture(pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
```

But I still get the same warnings :

```
[ WARN:0@11.531] global /output/build/opencv4-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1226) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: cannot find appsink in manual pipeline

[ WARN:0@11.532] global output/build/opencv4-4.5.5/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

`v4l2-ctl --list-devices`
outputs :

```
usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2
UVC Camera (046d:0825) (usb-500000.ehci-3):
        /dev/video0
        /dev/video1
        /dev/media0
```

`v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext`
returns :

```
usb 1-3: reset high-speed USB device number 2
ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
        Type: Video Capture

        [0]: 'YUYV' (YUYV 4:2:2)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 176x144
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x176
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 352x288
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 432x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 544x288
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 752x416
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 800x448
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 800x600
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 864x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 960x544
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 960x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1024x576
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1184x656
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x960
                        Interval: Discrete 0.133s (7.500 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
        [1]: 'MJPG' (Motion-JPEG, compressed)
                Size: Discrete 640x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 160x120
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 176x144
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x176
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 320x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 352x288
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 432x240
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 544x288
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 640x360
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 752x416
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 800x448
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 800x600
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 864x480
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 960x544
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 960x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1024x576
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1184x656
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x720
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
                Size: Discrete 1280x960
                        Interval: Discrete 0.033s (30.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.040s (25.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.050s (20.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.067s (15.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.100s (10.000 fps)
                        Interval: Discrete 0.200s (5.000 fps)
```

I have read many many forums posts, but I can not find any solution that works for me,

Many thanks,

Comment: are you sure that your device is 0: `/dev/video0` ?

Comment: Does this help ?  `appsink drop=1", cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)`

Comment: Hi @Miki, I have tested with others just in case, but I get the same error.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I just tested with "appsink drop=1" at the end of my pipeline, but same problem.

Comment: That it all I can.

Comment: After some investigations, looks like appsink is not installed by buildroot when building gstreamer. I have checked the options, I do not understand why it is not installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations, the Buildroot version I was using was corrupted in a non-evident way. Therefore, appsink was not installed while being selected in the menuconfig.

Moving to the latest version and building once again solved my issue.

To check the installed sinks, anyone can run :

```
gst-launch-1.0 | grep sink
```